# Why is my algorithm environment (algorithm2e) centered?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, algorithm2e

I have some Latex (below) which renders the algorithm environment with centered text:

[image]

This doesn't match the [wikibooks Latex documentation](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Algorithms), which shows a left-aligned block.

[image]

I'd rather not post all my Latex, since it's a big document, but I've tried to include relevant info below. Any help is appreciated!

#### My Latex

```
\documentclass[preprint]{imsart}

\RequirePackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\RequirePackage{amsthm,amsmath,amssymb}
\RequirePackage[round]{natbib}
\RequirePackage[colorlinks,citecolor=blue,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\RequirePackage{fullpage}
\RequirePackage{todonotes}
\RequirePackage{bm}
\RequirePackage{booktabs}
\RequirePackage{comment}
\RequirePackage{subcaption}
\RequirePackage{algorithm}
\RequirePackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}
\RequirePackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{macros}
\usepackage[]{algorithm2e}

...

\begin{document}

...

\subsection{This is a title}

This is some text.

\begin{algorithm}[H]
 \KwData{this text}
 \KwResult{how to write algorithm with \LaTeX2e }
 initialization\;
 \While{not at end of this document}{
  read current\;
  \eIf{understand}{
   go to next section\;
   current section becomes this one\;
   }{
   go back to the beginning of current section\;
  }
 }
 \caption{How to write algorithms}
\end{algorithm}

...

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looked like the `algorithm` and `algpseudocode` packages were messing with the `algorithm2e` package. The fix is to use just `algorithm2e`.